# Screen-saver inhibit script

Tags: bash, screensaver, qdbus, qdbusxml2cpp

I would like to automatize screen-saver inhibit, when using Firefox's "plugin-container" for flash player in KDE4. I did not write the [original script](https://blog.sleeplessbeastie.eu/2013/03/02/semi-intelligent-screensaver/) myself, but I fixed it a bit.

```
    #!/bin/sh
    # Simple script to demonstrate D-Bus usage
    while true
    do
      # read firefox plugin-container cpu usage
      ret=$(top -b -n1 -u "$(whoami)" | gawk '$12 ~ /plugin-containe/ { SUM += $9 }; END { print SUM }')
      if [ -n "$ret" ] && [ "$ret" -gt 15 ]; then
        idle_time=`qdbus org.kde.screensaver /ScreenSaver GetSessionIdleTime`
        if [ "$idle_time" -gt 50 ]; then
          qdbus org.kde.screensaver /ScreenSaver SimulateUserActivity
        fi
      fi

      sleep 50

done
```

Now when I run the script i get this error:

```
/home/geo/bin/plugin-containe: line 7: [: 68.75: integer expression expected
```

I tried to get top to output integer number but I couldn’t.

What can I do to fix?

Regards
Georges

Comment: If you believe the awk output is the problem then using `int(SUM)` will truncate that number to an integer.

Comment: Thank you so much Mr. Reisner, it works now flawlessly. I changed line 7 to   {print int(SUM)}'` .Regards Georges

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the `awk` output is the cause of the non-integer value then you can use the awk `int()` function to truncate the value of `SUM` to an integer value (i.e. `int(SUM)`).